# Why does setting the value of an input type file element using querySelecter work, but getElementById not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, reset

Recently, I ran into a problem with an input type file element that stopped displaying the file selection dialog box, but didn't display any errors in the the debugger/code inspector.  The element uses the jQuery wrap..reset..unwrap method to 'clear' the element.  However, about six months ago this all worked fine in chrome, firefox, edge, and internet explorer, but now, nothing, so something has changed.

I copied the input type element and the click and change event handling code used to process the files selected with this element into a new web-page up on [codepen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/zYOXQgz?editors=1010) to make it easier to demonstrate and work on.  Sorry, it is rather lengthy, but the part that clears the input type file element just before causing the element to display the file selection dialog is right near the top of the javascript code at lines 9 and 10, so not hard to see.

```
<form id="fileImageForm" style="display: inline;">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Get pictures" />
  <input type="text" id="text" style="width: 200px;" />
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" class="file"
         accept="image/jpeg, ... ,image/tiff" multiple
         style="display: none;" />
  <img id="fileImage" />
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById( 'button' )
  .onclick = function() {

               //
               // Reset the input file element so the file selection
               // dialog shows everytime the element is clicked ...
               //

/* line 9 */   document.getDocumentById( 'fileInput' ) .value  = '';

               // Or

/* line 10 */  document.querySelector( '.file' ) .value  = '';

               // Click the input file element ...

               document.getElementById( 'fileInput' ).click();
            };

  //
  // When the user chooses one or more files with the input file element,
  // the change event 'fires' and this function is called to validate and
  // preview the selected image(s) ...
  //

  function fileInputChange( event ) { ... }

  // Attach the change even to the input file element ...

  document.getElementById( 'fileInput' )
  .addEventListener( 'change', fileInputChange );

  ⫶
</script>
```

In any case here are two lines in question that I use in the new page to 'clear' the input type file element:

```
document.getDocumentById( 'fileInput' ) .value  = '';
document.querySelector( '.file' ) .value  = '';
```

Because I didn't want to work with jQuery in the codepen page, I went with the two most common javascript-only solutions that I could find.

While both of these use different methods to 'find' the input type file element, the 'clearing' is caused by directly assigning an empty string to the element's value.  Both ways work fine in the codepen in all of the current versions of the major browsers and seem quite straight forward.

The often used jQuery wrap-reset-unwrap method that is not shown, does its 'work' by enclosing the input type file element in a temporary form element, calling the form's reset method to indirectly 'clear' the input element, and then removing the temporary form element, but as I said above, this means of clearing the input element stopped working for me in the current version of chrome, at least in my web-app, possibly because the event handlers assigned to the element are being corrupted by the form element wrapping and unwrapping each the the input element is clicked, possibly a memory issue, I don't know.

So, why if, since in the current version of all of the major browsers, the direct value assignment method of clearing the input element works, should I use the jQuery method, especially since I am experiencing issues with it until I fully debug it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's simple. Never use jQuery.

Comment: ^^ and that's why comments need to be able to be downvoted

Comment: So, your question is: should you use jquery, that you know works, until you can find some vanilla method to get it to work?  Your question *isn't* how to fix it using vanilla javascript, but whether you should/not use jquery?

Comment: I'd be fine using the non-jquery method, as long as it always work, but since so many seem to use the jquery wrap-reset-unwarp vs assigning '' to the input element using javascript or .val(''), of which, the later I almost never see.  By the way, I like and regularly use jQuery, but why not use the most direct and fastest way to do this?